# Multiply/select every combination of an array to create a massive data set

Tags: python, arrays, element

I have an array ['cat','dog','rabbit','snake','sheep','cow','horse','pig'] and I want to output every combination of the elements, while also removing elements until the the data set includes one of each animal.

```
['cat','dog','rabbit']
['cat','dog',]
['cat']
['dog','rabbit']
['dog']
['cat','rabbit']
['rabbit']
```

but with a lot more data etc...

Are there any modules to help with this?

Thanls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from the standard library to combine the elements.

This module contains a lot of cool stuff for the kind of job you want to get done. The great part is that every function on this module, returns an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) instead of a list, so you can use it to create "on-demand" results, as combinatorial algorithms on large sets of data can be really expensive.